# Plotting a line between two points in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, coordinates, line

I have a csv file with a following format having four columns (as a `MWE`):

```
xcoord1,ycoord1,xcoord2,ycoord2
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3
0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
```

I want to plot a line from each `xcoord1,ycoord1` to `xcoord2,ycoord2` using gnuplot. For example in this case, I would draw two lines from `0.1,0.2` to `0.4,0.3` and `0.5,0.3` to `0.7,0.5`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution would be to preprocess your file and generate a Gnuplot script which would employ the `set arrow` command. Alternatively one can plot the input file directly with a little preprocessing. The trick is to convert each line in the data file into a separate block, e.g.,

```
xcoord1,ycoord1,xcoord2,ycoord2
0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3
0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
```

would be converted into

```
0.1 0.2
0.4 0.3

0.5 0.3
0.7 0.5
```

Gnuplot will then connect only points within one block. To achieve this, you could do:

```
plotCmd(fname)=sprintf("<gawk -F, 'NR>1{printf \"%%s\\t%%s\\n%%s\\t%%s\\n\\n\",$1,$2,$3,$4}' %s", fname)
plot plotCmd('input.csv') w lp
```

Answer (score 6):

Plot the lines as vectors without arrow heads:

```
plot "file" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors nohead
```