# How can I animate a line between two points in GNUplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm solving the pendulum's equation of motion, and I need to create an animation in GNUplot that shows the evolution of the system.
R4K provides me with the solution point by point, and this solution is stored in a .dat file named 'd' in columns 2 and 3. These are the orders given to GNUplot:

```
    set xrange [-2:2]
    set yrange [-2:2]
    set pointsize 2
    set style line 2 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7
    set object circle at first 0,0 size scr 0.01 \
        fillcolor rgb 'black’ fillstyle solid
    do for [ii=1:3762] {
    plot 'd.dat' using 2:3 every ::ii::ii linestyle 2
    pause 0.002
    }
```

I now want to connect the circle in [0,0] to the moving point plotted from d.dat with a moving line; how can I do it? I found a solution (kind of) [here](https://enteropia.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/animation-with-gnuplot-animating-pendulum/), but still I don't know how to tell GNUplot to search for a certain point in 'd.dat', different every time, and to draw the line between it and the centre.

Comment: Try `plot 'd.dat' using (0):(0):2:3 every ::ii::ii with vectors nohead` inside the loop. Instead of drawing a point at (x,y), it should draw a line from (0,0) to (x,y).

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked just fine! But what with the general procedure? I.e, what if I want to connect two generic points (both moving or both steady)?

Comment: I found the solution to the answer posed in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344294/plotting-a-line-between-two-points-in-gnuplot?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of user8153 is so far the best. Let me give a trial. If I were you I would have use arrows that update their positions with the moving end dynamically, since the `every` command loads one point at time. GNUPLOT provides environment variables such as `GPVAL_X_MIN, GPVAL_X_MAX, GPVAL_Y_MIN,...` that can be useful:

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set pointsize 2
set style line 2 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7
set object circle at first 0,0 size scr 0.01 \
    fillcolor rgb 'black’ fillstyle solid
do for [ii=1:3762] {
plot 'd.dat' using 2:3 every ::ii::ii linestyle 2
# makes GPVAL_ variables available 
xpos = GPVAL_X_MIN; ypos = GPVAL_Y_MIN # or MAX does not matter since you are
                                       # loading one point at time.
unset arrow # Remove the one of the previous graph
set arrow from 0, 0 to xpos, ypos nohead lc rgb 'black' 
replot
pause 0.002
}
```

I have no data to debug this code snippet, but I would have done something along this line. Later versions of GNUPLOT allow to use `stats` command that avoids `replot` (`replot` could have an effect here on the persistence of images of the film but I am not sure). You can also try something along the line

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set pointsize 2
set style line 2 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7
set object circle at first 0,0 size scr 0.01 \
    fillcolor rgb 'black’ fillstyle solid
do for [ii=1:3762] {
stats 'd.dat' using 2:3 every ::ii::ii # applied the statistical summary of 
                                       # the data file
xp = STATS_min_x; yp = STATS_min_y
unset arrow
set arrow from 0, 0 to xp, yp nohead lc rgb 'black'
plot 'd.dat' using 2:3 every ::ii::ii linestyle 2
pause 0.002
}
```

I have never used `STATS` with the every command (let me know the output just for fun).

Hope that helps